# Function return type depending on argument type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following code where the `useSearchResults` function (it's a React hook, but it doesn't matter) initializes the state based on the argument.
`config.state` can be anything defined in `SearchResultsState` or a function that returns anything defined in `SearchResultsState`.

The `state` returned by `useSearchResults` is defined as `Partial<SearchResultsState>` because, initially could be anything in that state type. I need `state` to be a partial `SearchResultsState` but also whatever type `config.state` has (an object or the object returned by a function or undefined).

I've trying and trying around this but couldn't find a solution.

```js
type State = Record<string, any>;
interface IWidget {
  State: State;
}
interface SearchResultsState extends State {
  a: number; 
  b: string;
}

interface SearchResultsWidget extends IWidget {
  State: SearchResultsState;
}
export type StateInitializerFunction<W extends IWidget> = () => Partial<W['State']>;
export type StateInitializer<W extends IWidget> = StateInitializerFunction<W> | Partial<W['State']>;

export type WidgetInitializer<W extends IWidget> = {
  state?: StateInitializer<W>;
};

export type WidgetWrapperResult<
  W extends IWidget,
> = {
  state: Partial<W['State']>;
};


const useSearchResults = (
  config: WidgetInitializer<SearchResultsWidget> = {},
): WidgetWrapperResult<SearchResultsWidget> => {
  const state = typeof config.state === 'function' ? config.state() : config.state || {};
  
  return { state };
};

const { state: { a, b } } = useSearchResults({ state: { a: 1 } });
// or const { state: { a, b } } = useSearchResults({ state: () => ({ a: 1 }) });

const test = (a: number) => console.log(a);

// error
test(a); // a is number | undefined and I'm looking to be just number because a is number in state
```

You can play with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/FAFwngDgpgBAyiAhiWBeGAlKBjA9gJwBMAeAZxHwEsA7AcwBoZFqwA%20AbmBpXwDNFssAJIB1SoVpQQMAN7AY8JCgBci5FE4BfLtR79B8KInzYAFllIBXADYhSCdTCgAPFNUKk1KWfKarqlgC2AEZQ%20OwwvsGq5FR0WsA6egKwcEYm5lBWtqRiElJOrlDunqLiktJyCg4qhsZmFjZ2NRrA2i4QBNLg0F5QQtSUIJSI1pQAXmEAYpbU2MO41MQihW4eMGX5IKww6AAUAJS7OwAKxsOjywDaAOQtNwC6HMAdXTA9qUr9gxdjk-jLVbFdabCo7dAtAZDEZ-aazeaURbLHYAHxgZ3wv2udy%20j2eL2cnUx70gsDyFShvwmYUBLjWpXJUnBPgU5HUAH5VJCfjDqQCRM9NJwCUTuqSYIyQCJ8IgINB8I1bMRfCs6cCGeUpPRgMyqjA2bUMViRLd7k8tMLgHhqOQYJZSFA0vVMtk7LsYHtfNbeJRaKpJZTef9iE6Moq7JLdZptQd-ZqpTK5WFwyH0g0sk1cvHwTs9dbbQa0CToLheDBvb6AHSF3aodA3XjwhbUG4wdnlxY%202jVr6HGCqCvdmsotEyIW%20Xz4KSWfDUWT6r4wcfjq2LW0yBfqVQbxCMYJLg-oe2OtMuzN7DeF7d%20GAARgPmgOwvz3Sy0n2iH8QVC%20COqB2%20a4NYUCVtYuC0HsiBPokKDkJBT5AA)

Comment: If you want a function's return type to depend on its argument type then you need to make it *generic* (or an overload, but that's not going to be very helpful here).  Once you use generics you need to make the generic type arguments inferrable from the inputs, but you can't do that with indexed access types like `W["state"]`.  So you'll need to refactor significantly to use that type directly, possibly as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3vZkN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the reason I couldn't get it to work until now. I'll wait for the explanation. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing that is missing is when config.state is a function, right?

Comment: Sorry, does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mLv6kw) work better?  If so I'll use that instead.

Comment: Yes, it works. Nice :)

Comment: One thing I omitted because I thought it won't be relevant is that `useSearchResults` is defined like this:

`const useSearchResults = <T extends AnyContent>(config: ...) => ...`

and it is used like `useSearchResults<Product>()`.

The thing now is that if I add what you suggested it says `useSearchResults` expects 2 type arguments, so seems it can't infer S :(
Do you know how can I solve that?

Comment:  This is the second time that you've said my answer solution sufficed and then came back with something that didn't work, causing me to stop writing an answer and deal with it. I asked "does that fully address the question" in the first place to prevent a situation like this, where I spend time explaining something that doesn't apply. At this point I think further questions are out of scope, sadly. Should I: write up the answer I'm currently working on and you ask another question post if you want? Or: disengage entirely and let someone else take over? Which would you prefer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253934/discussion-between-inakiabt-and-jcalz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a function's return type to depend on its argument type then you either need to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) it with multiple call signatures, or [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in some number of type parameters.  Overloads only work if you have a relatively small number of ways you want to call the function, while generics are more appropriate to represent an arbitrary relationship between input and output.

---

Overloads might work for this use case, if you only want to support the four possible cases for `a` and `b` being present or possibly absent, but it's tedious:

```
function useSearchResults(
  config: { state?: { a: number, b: string } | (() => { a: number, b: string }) }
): { state: { a: number, b: string } };
function useSearchResults(
  config: { state?: { a: number, b?: string } | (() => { a: number, b?: string }) }
): { state: { a: number, b?: string } };
function useSearchResults(
  config: { state?: { a?: number, b: string } | (() => { a?: number, b: string }) }
): { state: { a?: number, b: string } };
function useSearchResults(
  config: { state?: { a?: number, b?: string } | (() => { a?: number, b?: string }) }
): { state: { a?: number, b?: string } };

function useSearchResults(
  config: WidgetInitializer<SearchResultsWidget> = {},
): WidgetWrapperResult<SearchResultsWidget> {
  const state = typeof config.state === 'function' ? config.state() : config.state || {};

  return { state };
};

const { state: { a, b } } = useSearchResults({ state: { a: 1 } });
/* (property) state: {
  a: number;
  b?: string | undefined;
} */

useSearchResults({ state: () => ({ a: 1 }) }).state.a
```

---

That can quickly get out of hand, though, so you might need to use generics instead.  Once you use generics you need to make the generic type arguments *inferrable* from the inputs, but you can't do that with [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `W["state"]` (there was a pull request at [ms/TS#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) which would have made this possible, but it's not part of the language now.  A new PR at [ms/TS#53017](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/53017) might be merged eventually, but for now it's not.)

So you'll need to refactor significantly to use that type directly.  Possibly as shown here:

```
type StateInitializerFunction<S extends State> = () => S;
type StateInitializer<S extends State> = StateInitializerFunction<S> | S;
type WidgetInitializer<S extends State> = { state?: StateInitializer<S>; };
type WidgetWrapperResult<S extends State> = { state: S; };

const useSearchResults = <S extends Partial<SearchResultsState>>(
  config: WidgetInitializer<S> = {},
): WidgetWrapperResult<S & Partial<SearchResultsState>> => {
  const state = typeof config.state === 'function' ? config.state() : config.state || {};
  return { state } as any;
};
```

Here what I've done is replace mentions of `W` with just its `state` property type `S`. I've also replaced the `Partial` stuff in the definitions and moved it to the function. Now the function `useSearchResults` accepts a `WidgetInitializer<S>` for some `S` that extends `Partial<SearchResultsState>`, and it returns a `WidgetWrapperResults<S & Partial<SearchResultsState>>`.  That [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) just helps make sure the compiler is still aware of `b`'s existence when you don't pass it.  Let's test it:

```
const { state: { a, b } } = useSearchResults({ state: { a: 1 } });
/* (property) state: {
    a: number;
} & Partial<SearchResultsState> */

const test = (a: number) => console.log(a);

useSearchResults({ state: () => ({ a: 1 }) }).state.a

test(a);
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5AbgGwCZIN4Ch8kkAXATxmQGUSQTkBeJAJQngHsAnLAHihM4BLYAHMANEhDAyAPgDcRJMPqcAZgmQBJAOqCsIiCTyLiNOhABcSM-QXEAvouUQ1G6xBCd4AC1ZQArhgkUDbIEAAe9MBYUNa09MbExCBWwP5gAEYudkkZVvxCojmOTsAq6ojunj5+gcG6+oZIEVExSDp6BkYESXHmVlQeXr7QdSHxEMWKETBcRuSUffSawIIkgiAYggBeLgBi-sDw6+zAPNrNkRDRsR2NJDJITAAUAJRPjwAKnuub5wDaAHJQoCALryabhWaceYUagTFZrDZbXacc6XVq3BpdR5MUKI34o-aHY6CU7nR4AHyQ3xhyIBwImYIhkOhsMW2MMBOROxc6Ja1zadxxT0SSX45gA-AMEatCby0doIQ4FKy5qQ4UhOSRtJwQDBKJxakEeCYtRjBVjOoYxIpcWLiBL6FZaYSGSDwcVVcRVCSTsAkP4oBBBtURgEglBnmaOMBVIIRFZcEgnRBpXhJKl0llOBI8imBMIREh7Ehqc83h8MykkGlMi48-lC6IS+9HMRXkmC-1q1n67mkPmCkWSyWcr6jv7A8HQ8NjcFo71Y-HExnU+nkzW6zm8+nhy3S+XKwxHpu+zvB3vm8X7G3FJ21xMu1vsw3L03Cjex4oJ6TTtOQyGGpRkjRckmXBMu3XZ9023N8h2vUcj3eE9q1g18BwQz9WxLe8oKfNDz3gj8R1Lexxz9MkAyDQCw3nKMY1OFd8KlGCiMwq9sMPJAKxQ09JHQ-tdxIg87w7FjnUI2sMOEgsuO-H9KP-GjZ2AiMF0YuNIK1a0SG5TYFR4VTwzGbV7VwexbXEnT7l1fVDXnIygJMyMzIdJBY34bsEiYBYIHYVQPKYhMADpUyeBgmEBX9-UBJBJSCrSRDCiZKysCDkvCylqQs70kk4Qx-E4ANk3C8jFHKxRPO6bzLGrPNR1LJgVOc+jnlKgizyQABGRrXhyAB6AAqHiYE4dhDXId5UyTM0X37HJiAyTiR2pQ4sAgeNgAgLBiiQIaBsIYgWrokCFw6ntj0edrMx6nDbxS8wQpAI7Eq8+gvJeeacz4t72AwCAQowdgRGeEB+tegaBuaThxs4RQPpIMH+qQKHJCUWI4M4MtA2iTbhB2yRonaQEwCQYH2AAaxHEh2EHZAACsgyMLH6fgEAaPRwRMYwpQA1TQgSj8pZGBYNguF4fdxCJ2RVWcVxKmM+jQgtG4Rd7aSFsHESRDkXCZnVYX8TlHlUQOScqKM1W2lCe0rusBQDZhDVFmNpEDNRK2BTV23RTd+UzaUs4qCpB38Cd9lkG1fSiTRKhrdiX2mAu+h03902+RDvXyojl2o90uyDRcRz4+9m2JnM2qBmz1VqoApWztiJgvauNXXXpBv1PGcwZBkMCMqsaOTY9zPzMs-AH21QuHLOq2ADIaR+DvWsb23cVPKrTi88LfLhALEpXR6fMipBoqDuKEoyo+IDSg-QqynLyuIAqSCKkratHEBYikMgFEquuU51U3A1MiooTpzkbjdGaGtepkQhsNUa41JpkGmp1Oa7E-5IAXu3P4ncxi+wOoQOuiNRRg3Yr9Ty-1AbA1BuDVU4C1JjCgQRe2N0aywLbK8a+z1CCI2RnIIAA)