# Multiple type arguments inferring

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76391957/function-return-type-depending-on-argument-type) where [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) helped me to infer the input in order to return the correct type, now I need to pass a type argument and still inferring `S`:

```js
type StateInitializerFunction<S extends State> = () => S;
type StateInitializer<S extends State> = StateInitializerFunction<S> | S;
type WidgetInitializer<S extends State> = { state?: StateInitializer<S>; };
type WidgetWrapperResult<S extends State> = { state: S; };

type Model = Record<string, any>;

const useSearchResults = <M extends Model, S extends Partial<SearchResultsState>>(
  config: WidgetInitializer<S> = {},
): WidgetWrapperResult<S & Partial<SearchResultsState>> => {
  const state = typeof config.state === 'function' ? config.state() : config.state || {};
  console.log({} as M); // just for the sake of use it somewhere in the function
  return { state } as any;
};
```

But I get the following error when `useSearchResults` is used like:

```js
type Product = { id: string; sku: string };

const { state: { a, b } } = useSearchResults<Product>({ state: { a: 1 } });
```

Error:

```
Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
```

I've found that there's an open [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) that could solve this issue (seems like it's being [considered](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54298) to be included soon), but in the meantime, is there any workaround I can use?

Note: make `useSearchResults` to return a function as I've found isn't an option :(

Comment: "Note: make `useSearchResults` to return a function as I've found isn't an option :(" <-- *why*? You're saying "I need to open a can but a can opener isn't an option :(". It would be nice to hear an explanation there.  Anyway the workarounds I know of are listed in the answer to the question this duplicates.  There's currying (which you say you can't use) and something I call "dummying" (who knows if you can use that), both of which are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn81kW).  Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't look good as interface of the library I'm building, it's just an aesthetic issue :). Thanks for the clarification.